# Share WiFi connection through ethernet

Tags: connection

Using kali linux for this.

I went into the "Network Connections" and created a new connection under "Wired" and set it to "Shared to other computers" under the "IPv4" tab and it doesn't work. When I plug it into my Mac it shows the ip is self-assigned. Now when I load up kali linux on my laptop and do the same exact thing, it works. What am I doing wrong? Or is there an easier way to set this up?

EDIT: Tried using bridge-utils by running the following commands:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1
```

and get an error message: `Operation not supported`

Comment: Is your Pi supposed to be a DHCP server that assigns your mac an IP address via Ethernet? (Not too familiar with Kali)

Comment: I just set it up like I explained on the full desktop version of kali but yeah it didn't work. I did try use bridge-utils , is that a good option?

Comment: OpenWRT supports raspberry pi, maybe that's an option for you: https://code.google.com/p/raspberrypi-openwrt/

Comment: Please Clarify: You have a PI with ethernet and wifi. And you want to share the Ehternet with a desktop PC?

Or perhaps: You have a PI with ethernet and wifi. And you want to share the wifi with other wifi devices?

Comment: I connected to wifi and wanted to share it via ethernet. I edited OP mentioning that I tired "bridge-utils" but did not work.

Comment: I'm doing this right now, so I can tell you how I do it, at least. I enabled internet sharing via ethernet on system preferences -> sharing, connected the pi and the mac via ethernet, then installed netatalk on the pi (sudo apt-get install netatalk), then started it up (sudo /etc/init.d/netatalk start), and on my shared section in finder I saw 'raspberrypi'. I went on 'Connect as...', logged in, and that was all. Very fast process.

Comment: @BenjaminJB Looks like you have it backwards of what I want to do. I want to share the pi's internet connection to the mac.

Comment: @Aaron - your mac says it has a self-assigned address - what are you intending to do about this? is the Pi going to assign it an address via DHCP, or are you going to configure some static addresses on the Pi and the computer?

Comment: @user2813274 When I did the same method on my laptop, the mac generated an IP itself. When doing it on the pi, it got confused and said it has a generic self assigned address. Doing the same exact method.

Comment: @Aaron - can you explain how the laptop generating an IP address for itself differs from it getting a generic self-assigned address? or better yet, a packet capture on that interface showing what happens when you connect it to A vs to B.

Comment: @user2813274 Well when I share wifi through ethernet to the computer, it gets a real LAN IP and shows the IP of the gateway, etc. When I do it on the pi it doesn't do that, it says its a "self-assigned IP" like 169.254.198.122 and it doesnt get any internet connection. But the steps that I'm sharing them with on the laptop compared to the pi are exactly the same.